# I'm trying to add a link (to a webinar) in a Calendar invite attached to an email

Tags: apex, calendar, emailfileattachment

Starting with Doug Ayers' Visualforce solution (thank you, Doug!) (https://douglascayers.com/2015/01/09/salesforce-send-calendar-invites-in-visualforce-email-templates/), I create the invite as a String and attach it to the email, which seems to be working well for capturing most of the event details, but I would like to include a link in the description, as this particular project is about webinar registrations.  The 'DESCRIPTION:' field/node is not a fan of HTML, apparently, and drops everything after the first suggestion of a tag.

Here's the code for the text string:

```
    public static String createCalendarInvite_EST(String organizerEmail, String slabel, DateTime startDT, DateTime endDT, String summary, String description) {

    String newLine = '\n';
    String result = 'BEGIN:VCALENDAR';
    result += newLine + 'METHOD:PUBLISH';
    result += newLine + 'VERSION:2.0';
    result += newLine + 'PRODID::-//hacksw/handcal//NONSGML v1.0//EN';
    result += newLine + 'BEGIN:VEVENT';
    result += newLine + 'ORGANIZER:mailto:' + organizerEmail;
    result += newLine + 'DTSTAMP;TZID=America/New_York:' + startDt.format('yyyyMMdd') + 'T' + startDt.format('yyyyMMddHHmmssZ').right(11).left(6);
    result += newLine + 'UID:' + slabel;
    result += newLine + 'DTSTART;TZID=America/New_York:' + startDt.format('yyyyMMdd') + 'T' + startDt.format('yyyyMMddHHmmssZ').right(11).left(6);
    result += newLine + 'DTEND;TZID=America/New_York:' + endDT.format('yyyyMMdd') + 'T' + endDT.format('yyyyMMddHHmmssZ').right(11).left(6);
    result += newLine + 'SUMMARY:' + summary;
    result += newLine + 'DESCRIPTION:' +    description;
    result += newLine + 'BEGIN:VALARM';
    result += newLine + 'TRIGGER:-PT1D';
    result += newLine + 'ACTION:DISPLAY';
    result += newLine + 'DESCRIPTION:Reminder';
    result += newLine + 'END:VALARM';
    result += newLine + 'END:VEVENT';
    result += newLine + 'END:VCALENDAR';

    return result;

}
```

(I've hard-coded the date/time as EST; GMT was resulting in a disconnect between the values as they appeared in the email body and the calendar entry, and I took a hammer to it.  I'll revisit that another time ...)

I see where adding the email address after 'ORGANIZER:mailto:' works cleanly; does anyone have experience creating links in a related way?

Comment: *Does anyone have experience with...?* is not a question you actually care about the answer to. What you should really ask (and you removed my attempt to fix via edit) is *How do I...?*

Comment: Sorry, Adrian -- didn't mean to overwrite.  Makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

I'd go with the answer to [HTML in iCal attachment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/859475/54026) from StackOverflow.

> It is not strictly forbidden by the RFC, but DESCRIPTION is not the appropriate property for HTML content.
>
> DESCRIPTION should be the plain text version of your content. The property X-ALT-DESC with a FMTTYPE declaration of text/html is the appropriate property for HTML content.

Combining that with the C# example from [Using X-ALT-DESC / Applying HTML to calendar invites in Outlook](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31255125/54026) gives something like the following in Apex:

```
result += newLine + 'DESCRIPTION:' +    description;
string html_body = '<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2//EN">' +
        '\n<html>' +
        '\n<head>' +
        '\n<title></title>' +
        '\n</head>' +
        '\n<body>';
html_body += '<p>Hello <b>Bold</b> New World</p>';
html_body += '</body>\n</html>';
result += newLine + 'X-ALT-DESC;FMTTYPE=text/html:' + html_body;
result += newLine + 'BEGIN:VALARM';
```

You might need to experiment with the new line characters a bit.

Comment: Thanks, Daniel - I've been working with variations this morning, and as I have gmail I've been looking at how it works there, and neither DESCRIPTION nor X-ALT-DESC are resulting in anything appearing in the Description field of the calendar entry.  I'm going to spend time with iCalendar.org (https://icalendar.org/iCalendar-RFC-5545/3-1-content-lines.html) and see what that yields.

Comment: Correction: The Description is appearing; the email is being delayed significantly, and I was validating an earlier iteration.  The iCalendar validator is proving quite useful, meanwhile.